# How to format the linked list using <<= operator in C++

Tags: c++, graph, linked-list

I'm having a problem formatting this linked list into what it say in the TODO comment. The error I am getting is:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:

Graph.h: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Graph::formatList()’:
Graph.h:63:14: error: invalid operands of types ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ and ‘LinkedListPtr {aka LinkedList<char>*}’ to binary ‘operator<<’
          str << adjList << endl;
          ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
Graph.h:65:17: error: could not convert ‘str’ from ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
          return str;
                 ^~~
```

My question is mostly how to use the `<<=` operator in this situation.

I've tried to create a string and append the linked list to it, I have tried to use `str <<` as seen in the code and `cout <<` but that library is not included in that class.

```
string formatList(){

    /* TODO (2):
     *
     * Return a string representation of the list. 
     * 
     * Each list should be written on a separate line, using the LinkedList's
     * <<() function.
     * 
     * Sample:
     * [ B, D ]
     * [ A ]
     * [ D ]
     * [ A, C ]
     */
     string str;

     str << adjList << endl;

     return str;        

}// end displayList()
```

Here is the method overloaded `<<=` method

```
virtual string toString() const{

    ostringstream oss;

    oss << "[ ";
    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        nodeptr_t iter = head->next;
        while ( iter->next != tail ) {
            oss << iter->element << ", ";
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        oss << iter->element << " ";
    }
    oss << "]";

    return oss.str();
}// end toString()
```

The expectation I have is to have the output look like:

```
[ B, D ]    
[ A ]    
[ D ]    
[ A, C ]
```

Instead of an error obviously.

Thanks.

Comment: A member `toString()` function is not the same as an `operator<<` overload. You have to call the `toString()` function, it will not happen automatically. You might also review the documentation for `std::string`, you're using it incorrectly. It is not a stream.

Comment: We need more code. What is `adjList`? If `adjList` is overloaded for extractions, then you can `std::ostringstream oss; oss << adjList; str = oss.str();`. If `adjList` is just a `std::string`, then `str += adjList;` should do the job.

Comment: Sorry, adjList is just a linked list of nodes. And I can't call the toString method because it is in a different class. I have to use the overloaded operator somehow

Comment: @jharre.99 -- Does your code compile if you do this `std::cout << adjList;`?  If not, get it to work there first, as that is what the previous comments are pointing out.  As a matter of fact, that is the first thing you should have coded/tested, and that is to see if `adjList` will work for the output stream, i.e. console, let alone strings.

Comment: The error messages seems to indicate that `str` is declared as `string *str`, a pointer to a string.  Is this your real code?

Comment: Graph.h: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Graph::formatList()’:
Graph.h:63:14: error: invalid operands of types ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ and ‘LinkedListPtr {aka LinkedList<char>*}’ to binary ‘operator<<’
          str << adjList << endl;
          ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
Graph.h:65:17: error: could not convert ‘str’ from ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
          return str;
sorry here is the error for this code, didn't realize. tried changing it to a ptr

Comment: @jharre.99 that error message does not match the code you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toString()` is looping through the list incorrectly. It needs to look more like this instead:

```
virtual string toString() const {
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "[ ";
    if ( !isEmpty() ) {
        nodeptr_t iter = head;
        while ( iter != tail ) {
            oss << iter->element << ", ";
            iter = iter->next;
        }
        oss << iter->element << " ";
    }
    oss << "]";
    return oss.str();
}// end toString()
```

And then you can implement your `operator<<` like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const LinkedList &list) {
    os << list.toString();
    return os;
}
```

As for the error message, it doesn't match the code you showed. The error message is referring to a `std::string*` pointer, but in the code you showed it is using a `std::string` object instead. But either way, your implementation of `formatList()` is still wrong and should look more like this instead:

```
string formatList() {

    /* TODO (2):
     *
     * Return a string representation of the list.
     *
     * Each list should be written on a separate line, using the LinkedList's
     * <<() function.
     *
     * Sample:
     * [ B, D ]
     * [ A ]
     * [ D ]
     * [ A, C ]
     */
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << *adjList << endl;
    return oss.str();
}// end displayList()
```